# Didn't include a pendingIntent in the extras?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I came across this Error message on Logcat while working on an app. Can anyone tell me what it means?

```
07-24 23:34:20.288    1140-1140/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
07-24 23:34:20.288    1140-1140/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras
```

**For your information:** I used an AlarmManager in this app

Comment: Just a heads up: I used an AlarmManager in this app

Comment: hi.. did you solve ur problem?Same issue here. can you pls post your answer?

Comment: my problem was in the build.grade file, I don't recall exactly what it was though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably means that you are missing a uses-library deceleration inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. 
If you can provide 1 line of the log just before getting this error message it will be helpful. 
You can try and fix it by adding the:

```
uses-library android:name="com.<your library>" /
```

under the

```
<application
```

Comment: Thanks. Will appreciate if you click the vote up button. (-:

Comment: Hello @EyalSooliman, can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156622/android-pendingintent-required-only-on-some-phones

Answer (score 1):

For me I Solved this Error by Giving the right parameter to `POST` Response in  Asynchronous task.

As we see in logcat `E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app`.This error shows that we are not added the right parameter to `POST` response.

Previously I had added the parameter like this:

```
  entity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody("23.234234"));
                  entity.addPart("longtitude", new StringBody("22.234324"));
                  entity.addPart("note", new StringBody("20"));
                  entity.addPart("parking_title", new StringBody("Drop"));
                  entity.addPart("filename[0]", new StringBody("199"));
                  entity.addPart("filename[1]", new StringBody("10"));
                  entity.addPart("filename[2]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
```

Then I changed into this:

```
  entity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody(lat_str));
                  entity.addPart("longtitude", new StringBody(long_str));
                  entity.addPart("note", new StringBody(note_str));
                  entity.addPart("parking_title", new StringBody(parking_titleStr));

                  entity.addPart("filename[0]", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));
```