# Android Errors After Creating Signed APK

Tags: android, apk

I am setting up a project to use Google's OAUTH Login. I had to create a signed APK then add the sha1 to the apps settings on google's site.

One section asked me to add my package name. I added it in,

After finishing configuration I know have this error,

```
channel
'4abe725 com.mysite.mysite/com.mysite.mysite.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : 
Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
```

Please notice this package name is being repeated,

```
com.mysite.mysite/com.mysite.mysite.MainActivity
```

I am wondering if my apps configuration is broken now that I created the signed apk. How can I change the file path if that is the problem?

webview.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

webview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button button;

private GoogleApiClient client;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Check your themes.xml file(s) and compare them to your supported SDK versions as seen in the appropriate .gradle and manifest files.

Comment: Are you implying that I am trying to use a different sdk than my targets?

Comment: The app runs it just crashes when I select the button to load my webview in my webview.xml. Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot this to make sure its not just an error having nothing to do with the signed apk?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you I updated my question with the information you just mentioned. If you don't mind taking a look I would appreciate it. I still cannot pinpoint what the error is.

Comment: Check out these two threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004006/how-can-i-get-the-intent-extras-for-a-pendingintent-that-is-already-pending and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617359/didnt-include-a-pendingintent-in-the-extras, based on the configuration error.